# DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object

Tags: linux

My laptop are on dual boot(Linux(Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and Windows) state, when I boot my OS.
during boot, this massage displayed:
"DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object"
How can solve this error:
help me!

Answer (score 0):

Not really anything to worry about. The tables it's complaining about are created by your machine's BIOS though so probably worth checking for BIOS updates